# How to select items that belong to a model depending on a boolean in model

Tags: ruby-on-rails

so I have a model :note that belongs to model :folder that takes a :folder_id. The :folder model takes a :privacy boolean that should determine whether the folder's notes can be seen by other users or not in the users#show view. So if :privacy is set to true, the folder's notes can't be seen, but they can be viewable if :privacy is set to false.

So far, I've been able to display public :folders with the following instance variable in my user_controller:

```
@public_folders = @user.folders.where(privacy: false)
```

And I've been able to get a :folder's notes when a :folder_id param is present with this:

```
@folder_notes = @user.notes.where(folder_id: params[:folder_id])
```

So my question is, how can I select all :notes that belong to any :folder where the :privacy is set to false?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@user.notes.joins(:folder).where(folders: { privacy: false })
```

Although, I'd make that a scope on `Note`:

```
scope :with_public_folders, -> { joins(:folder).where(folders: { privacy: false }) }
```

...and then you can do:

```
@user.notes.with_public_folders
```